# Play & Joda: How to serialize an Option[DateTime] with a given `Writes`

Tags: json, playframework, jodatime

The internal representation of my dates should always be ISO format with UTC timezone (I'm using the `Reads`/`Writes` for Joda provided by Play):

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.Reads._
import play.api.libs.json.Writes._

scala> val dateTime = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC)
dateTime: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2014-08-12T21:10:24.048Z

scala> val js = Json.toJson(dateTime)(jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "2014-08-12T21:10:24Z"
```

So far so good... but if I try to serialize an `Option[DateTime]` I always get this error:

```
scala> val js = Json.toJson(Some(dt))(jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.Writes[org.joda.time.DateTime]
 required: play.api.libs.json.Writes[Some[org.joda.time.DateTime]]
              Json.toJson(Some(dt))(jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
```

If I omit the `Writes` it works... but of course the format is not the one I'm looking for:

```
scala> val js = Json.toJson(Some(dateTime))
js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = 1407878787365
```

Is there a way to serialize an `Option[DateTime]` providing a specific `Writes`?

Then, my last issue is that whan I try to deserialize a JSON ISO date with UTC timezone like this...

```
val date = Json.parse(""" { "date": "2014-08-12T21:10:24Z" }""")

scala> val dt = date as (__ \ 'date).readNullable[DateTime](jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
dt: Option[org.joda.time.DateTime] = Some(2014-08-12T21:10:24.000+02:00)
```

... I get back a `DateTime` in local timezone even if I specified pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"`.

Is there another option than writing my own `Writes`? Tx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Writes.nullable(jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
```

That will serialize an `Option[DateTime]` but if the value is `None`, no field will be written.

```
Writes.optionWithNull(jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z"))
```

This will also serialize an `Option[DateTime]` but will write `null` if the value is `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also define your own implicits like that:

```
implicit object jodaDateTimeFormat extends Format[DateTime] {

    private lazy val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")

    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[DateTime] = json match {
      case JsNumber(d) => JsSuccess(new DateTime(d.toLong)) // Parse timestamps
      case JsString(d) => JsSuccess(dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(d))  // Parse ISO 8601 Dates
      case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(JsonValidationError("error.expected.date"))))
    }
    def writes(d: DateTime): JsValue = JsNumber(d.getMillis)
}

implicit object jodaDateTimeOptionFormat extends Format[Option[DateTime]] {

  private lazy val dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")

  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Option[DateTime]] = json match {
    case JsNumber(d) => JsSuccess(Some(new DateTime(d.toLong))) // Parse timestamps
    case JsString(d) => JsSuccess(Some(dateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(d)))  // Parse ISO 8601 Dates
    case _ => JsError(Seq(JsPath() -> Seq(JsonValidationError("error.expected.date"))))
  }
  def writes(d: Option[DateTime]): JsValue = if (d.isDefined) JsNumber(d.get.getMillis) else JsNull
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
implicit val dateWrites = jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
implicit val dateReads = jodaDateReads("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.scala#L411

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.scala#L645